# C# How to get date from calendar.SelectedDate in format dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, datetime-format

I need to get selected date from calendar and show it in textbox in format dd/MM/yyyy. I have this code, but it does not work.

```
datum_odevzdani.Text = (calendar_odevzdani.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: That code works fine, assuming the code you haven't posted works. Since you haven't posted any other code, I'm going to assume it all works. Congratulations! Your code is fine.

Comment: What does _"Does not work"_ mean?

Comment: I have this in error list: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @AntP Neither is the code fine, nor is `SelectedDate` a string. Instead, it is `Nullable<DateTime>`. That's why OP gets a compiler error.

Comment: @Clemens The code is fine. Point being, there is nothing in the code supplied to indicate that `calendar_odevzdani` is a `Calendar` control (and hence nothing to suggest that `SelectedDate` is not a valid `DateTime` object). Because the question is incomplete.

Comment: @AntP What about the `Calendar.SelectedDate` part of the question title?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The type of the [`Calendar.SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.selecteddate.aspx) property is `Nullable<DateTime>`. Hence you have to access the contained `DateTime` by the [`Nullable<T>.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property:

```
if (calendar_odevzdani.SelectedDate.HasValue)
{
    datum_odevzdani.Text = calendar_odevzdani.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```